# Move a folder between TFS2012 projects

Tags: tfs

I've got a Visual Studio solution sitting in a subfolder of a TFS project (let's call it `$/ProjectA/Main/Source/MyVsSolution`), and I need to move the solution into a different project (say `$/ProjectB/Main/Source/MyVsSolution`).

Note that I have each TFS project mapped to its own workspace, e.g. "$/ProjectA" maps to C:\Dev\ProjectA, "$/ProjectB" to C:\Dev\ProjectB, etc.

If I try to move the folder using Source Control Explorer I get an error message saying "Source control folder is not mapped to a local folder", presumably because where I'm trying to move the folder to is not in the same workspace?

I'm not sure where the practice came from, but I've always created separate workspaces for my TFS projects. Could I instead create a single workspace that maps `$/' to`C:\Dev`? I'm guessing this would allow me to move the folder, but are there any drawbacks to having one workspace that encompasses multiple projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181378.aspx), the drawbacks are using unnecessary network bandwidth and local disk space. That being said, I've always mapped to the root of the collection and haven't experienced any issues.

Comment: If you map `$/` but don't do a get on `$/` (only get `$/ProjectA` and `$/ProjectB`) then the network bandwidth will not be different than if you had two workspaces with one mapping each or one workspace with two mappings.